# mongodb $elemMatch using $ne not working as expected

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to return events where someone has not been invited to. However,
all my queries are returning data. Nothing should be returned when I run the query. What am I missing?

```
 "__v" : 0,
        "_id" : ObjectId("565cca79a9baa9b1522b57eb"),
        "attendees" : [
        {
        "_id" : ObjectId("565cca79a9baa9b1522b57ec"),
        "attendee" : ObjectId("557dfb4fc8c9ecbb07c2f98c"),
        "statustext" : "Accepted",
        "status" : 1
        },
        {
        "attendee" : ObjectId("55dec11f38180102145d0060"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("565f6bacdcbac0a6a354420c"),
        "statustext" : "Pending",
        "status" : 0
        }
        ]

db.events.find({attendees:{$elemMatch:{attendee:{$ne:"55dec11f38180102145d0060"}}}}).

db.events.find({attendees:{$elemMatch:{attendee:{$ne:'55dec11f38180102145d0060'}}}})

db.events.find({attendees:{$elemMatch:{attendee:{$ne:ObjectId('55dec11f38180102145d0060')}}}})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the docs:

> The $elemMatch operator matches documents that contain an array field
>   with at least one element that matches all the specified query
>   criteria.

That means the `$elemMatch` is not suited for this case.

```
db.events.find({"attendees.attendee":{$ne: ObjectId("55dec11f38180102145d0060")}})
```